# ASP.NET HTTP PUT and DELETE produce 404 status

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get familiar with ASP.NET, but I'm stuck at this basic thing.

So this is my HomeController.

[image: Home Controller]

I am using postman to simulate HTTP requests, but only GET method is working. PUT and DELETE both produce 404.

[image]

I have tried changing all the annotations to HttpGet, just to make sure that I'm targeting a correct method in my URL and it produces correct results. When I change the annotations back to HttpPut and HttpDelete, with the same links (but changed methods accordingly in postman) I get 404 again...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it looks like you have `Home/Put` as the url - you should just use `Home`

Comment: @DanielA.White It still produces the same 404 error. Starting to think it's a problem related to my IIS Express.

Comment: i would consider using a web api controller.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yeah, it works now. I made a new Web API project and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

seems you are calling bad just need make the request without the method like this

- http://localhost:5237/Home

don't use "/Put" same rule for "Delete" or "Post"

if your are using jQuery ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:5237/Home',

type: 'PUT'<---GET, POST, PUT, DELETE

....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the scenario and tested through POSTMAN its working for me.

Please select the verb as in figure

[image]

Seems the url to be used as below where xxxx is port number:

PUT  = (http://localhost:xxxx/home/put)

DELETE  = (http://localhost:xxxx/home/delete)

@Nemanja, Please let me know if this works.

Comment: I have tried all of those things, but none are working. I think the problem was related to some kind of configuration of my server. Made a new project in Visual Studio where I checked WebAPI checkbox, and all HTTP methods are now working.